# Can't access the specified url using rest and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am trying to get data using REST api from html form using angularjs and do some db operation on it. I am getting 404 error for the rest link specifid.
Here's my js code

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("mycon",function($scope,$http){
 console.log("entered here");
 $scope.test={};
 $scope.add = function() {
  console.log("entered here");
 var json=JSON.stringify($scope.test);
 console.log($scope.test);
 console.log(json);
 
$http({
     url: "rest/xyz/role",
     method: "GET",
     data: json,
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
     
    })
    .success(function(data, status,header,config) {
       
            $scope.data = data;
            
        
    }).error(function(data, status,header,config) {
        alert("error");
    });
  

 
}});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mycon">

<center>
<h2> Login Here! </h2>
<hr/>
 <form >
 
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Signum Id:</td> 
   <td><input type="text" ng-model="test.sig"/></td>
  
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" ng-click="add()" name="action"> Submit <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  
 </form>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


</body>
```

and my REST code goes here.

```
@Path("/xyz")
```

public class RestServices {

```
@GET
@Path("/role")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public String list() {
    //do db operation

}
```

}

After deploying and running the project on server, I am getting following error:
http://localhost:8080/LoginEmployee/rest/xyz/role "404 NOT FOUND".

Comment: After deploying can you manually access http://localhost:8080/LoginEmployee/rest/xyz/role e.g. just putting that URL in the browser. Do you see your intended response?

Comment: no, I cannot access url manually too. Same error. 404

Comment: I think problem in your java code, not in Angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Add servlet mapping in web.xml as "rest/*". and also check the project name which should be "LoginEmployee"

Comment: also check for the server port number where it is deployed.

Comment: which server you are using for deployment?

Comment: Use this init param in servlet <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> with values as the package name where the resource should get scanned

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `rest/` from `$http` param.

> `url: "xyz/role",`